# How to fix "Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime." error when attempting running on gpu?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been running my tensorflow programs on my CPU. However, it's been getting slow, so I wanted to set up a gpu environment to run it on my 1070ti. However, when after downloading CUDA 9.0 and CUDNN 7.4, tensorflow-gpu has trouble running it.

The error appears whenever I try importing tensorflow in python. I have tensorflow installed in a virtualenv environment, and the script running is inside the folder.

```
import tensorflow
```

I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\machinelearning\machinelearning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\machinelearning\machinelearning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\machinelearning\machinelearning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\machinelearning\machinelearning\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\machinelearning\machinelearning\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\machinelearning\machinelearning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\machinelearning\machinelearning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\machinelearning\machinelearning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\machinelearning\machinelearning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\machinelearning\machinelearning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\machinelearning\machinelearning\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\machinelearning\machinelearning\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\Documents\machinelearning\machinelearning\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22794), these packages don't work on Windows 10:

- Tensorflow 1.12.0
- Cuda toolkit 10.0.130
- cudnn 7.4.1.5

However, someone said that you can try to downgrade Tensorflow to version 1.10 using pip:

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.10.0
```

Comment: "No matching distribution found"